# mysql not in issue

Tags: mysql, select

I have a select statement that I am trying to build a list of scripts as long as the users role is not in the scripts.sans_role_priority field.  This works great if there is only one entry into the field but once I add more than one the whole function quits working.  I am sure I am overlooking something simple, just need another set of eyes on it.  Any help wold be appreciated.

script:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM scripts 
 WHERE active = 1 
   AND homePage='Y' 
   AND (role_priority > 40 OR role_priority = 40) 
   AND (40 not in (sans_role_priority) ) 
 ORDER BY seq ASC
```

data in scripts.sans_role_priority(varchar) = "30,40".

Additional testing adds this:
When I switch the values in the field to "40, 30"  the select works.  Continuing to debug...

Comment: You should *never* store delimited, multi-value data in a single table column. This basically goes against just about every rule of relational data systems

Comment: @Phil, +100 for `CSV is evil`

Comment: so the answer that I am getting besides I am going to hell for having a list in a varchar(j/k) is to build a relational table that requires me to do a join or an internal select

Comment: Yep, a join is the answer if you want to stay out of CSV-hell. see my updated question. Note that the join is an anti-join, that is, it filters out all values for which the join is true. No need for a subselect though :-)

Comment: Ok, after convincing myself, with the help of everyone else here, that I was doing it wrong.  I added a table to house the relationship of roles not allowed to access a script, changed my select and I am in business.  Thanks.

Comment: Updated SQL:SELECT * 
 FROM scripts 
 WHERE active = 1 
   AND homePage='Y' 
   AND (role_priority > 40 OR role_priority = 40) 
   AND 40 NOT in(Select roles from roles_sans_scripts where scripts_id = scripts.id) 
 ORDER BY seq ASC

Comment: @user967336, that query will work.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you are looking for [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

```
SELECT * 
 FROM scripts 
 WHERE active = 1 
   AND homePage='Y' 
   AND (role_priority > 40 OR role_priority = 40) 
   AND NOT FIND_IN_SET('40', sans_role_priority) 
 ORDER BY seq ASC
```

Note that having "X,Y,Z" as VARCHAR values in some fields reveals that your DB schema may be improved in order to have X, Y and Z stored as separate values in a related table.

Comment: I don't see how that resolves my issue, having a relational table that maps script to roles not allowed when the same is accomplished by just having a list of roles in the script record that are not allowed to access that script.  BTW your updated select does not change the my result.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM scripts
 WHERE active = 1 
   AND homePage='Y' 
   AND role_priority >= 40 
   AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(40,sans_role_priority)
 ORDER BY seq ASC
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Note that CSV in databases is just about the worst antipattern you can find.
It should be avoided at all costs because:

- You cannot use an index on a CSV field *(at least not a mentally sane one)*;
- Joins on CSV fields are a major PITA;
- Selects on them are uber-slow;
- They violate 1NF.
- They waste storage.

Instead of using a CSV field, consider putting `sans_role_priority` in another table with a link back to scripts.

```
table script_sans_role_priority
-------------------------------
script_id integer foreign key references script(id)
srp integer
primary key (script_id, srp)
```

Then the renormalized select will be:

```
 SELECT s.* 
 FROM scripts s
 LEFT JOIN script_sans_role_priority srp 
   ON (s.id = srp.script_id AND srp.srp = 40)
 WHERE s.active = 1 
   AND s.homePage='Y' 
   AND s.role_priority >= 40 
   AND srp.script_id IS NULL
 ORDER BY seq ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
 FROM scripts 
 WHERE active = '1' 
   AND homePage='Y' 
   AND role_priority >= '40'
   AND sans_role_priority <> '40'
 ORDER BY seq ASC
```